# VB Error "object required"

Tags: vbscript

I'm getting an "object required" error on line 54, the last line, when I run the following script. What is wrong?

```
 Option Explicit
Dim cmdString, g_strHostFile, filepath, flexnetpath, importcmd, dtmToday, dtmYesterday, dtmFileDate, param1, param2, param3, i4path, objFSO, objTextStream, g_strComputer, WshShell
'Initialize global constants and variables.
Const FOR_READING = 1
g_strHostFile = "D:\dataimports\LUM_servers.txt"
i4path = "C:\IFOR\WIN\BIN\i4blt.exe"
filepath = "D:\DataImports\"
flexnetpath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Flexnet\Manager\Admin"
importcmd = flexnetpath & "flexnet bulkimport -uadmin -padmin -f" & filepath
dtmToday = Date()
dtmYesterday = Date() - 1
dtmFileDate = Year(Date) & padDate(Month(Date)) & padDate(Day(Date))
param1 = "-r1 -e2,4 -n "
param2 = " -v 'Dassault Systemes' -b "
param3 = " -g "
WScript.Echo "i4Path: " & i4path
WScript.Echo "FilePath: " & filepath
WScript.Echo "flexnetpath: " & flexnetpath
WScript.Echo "importcmd: " & importcmd
WScript.Echo "dtmToday: " & dtmToday
WScript.Echo "dtmYesterday: " & dtmYesterday
WScript.Echo "dtmFileDate: " & dtmFileDate

'Read LUM Server Names from text file.
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FileExists(g_strHostFile) Then
  Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(g_strHostFile, FOR_READING)
Else
  WScript.Echo "Input file " & g_strHostFile & " not found."
  WScript.Quit
End If
'Loop through list of computers and perform tasks on each.
Do Until objTextStream.AtEndOfStream
  g_strComputer = objTextStream.ReadLine
WScript.Echo "Processing Server: " & g_strComputer
Set cmdString = i4path & param1 & g_strComputer & param2 & dtmYesterday & param3 & dtmToday & filepath & g_strComputer & "_" & dtmFileDate & "_lum.lrl"
WScript.Echo "Processing Command: " & cmdString
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmdString"
Loop
objTextStream.Close
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo "Processing Bulk Import: " & importcmd
WshShell.Run "importcmd"

Function padDate(intNumber)
 if intNumber <= 9 Then
  padDate = "0" & CStr(intNumber)
 Else
  padDate = CStr(intNumber)
 End If
End Function
```

Comment: on which line are you getting this error?

Comment: Do you know about where the error is being raised? Could you use `WScript.Echo` or `MsgBox` with some text just so that you can narrow down the area in the code where the error is happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few problems, I think.

```
 importcmd = flexnetpath & "flexnet bulkimport -uadmin -padmin -f" & filepath
```

You probably need some spaces:

```
 importcmd = flexnetpath & " flexnet bulkimport -uadmin -padmin -f " & filepath
```

Set is only used with objects, not strings, so it should be removed from this line:

```
 Set cmdString = i4path & param1 & g_strComputer & param2 & dtmYesterday & param3 & dtmToday & filepath & g_strComputer & "_" & dtmFileDate & "_lum.lrl"
```

I am fairly sure you either mean

```
 WshShell.Run importcmd
```

Or

```
 WshShell.Run """" & importcmd & """"
```

Answer (score 8):

Object required is raised when you have a statement like `Set x = y` where x is not an object type, but is instead an simple type (`Integer`, `Double`, `Date`, etc. ). I think the line

```
Set cmdString = i4path & param1 & g_strComputer & param2 & ...
```

is causing the error, and I think all you have to do is remove the `Set` statement. I think strings do not derive from `Object` and thus do not need the `Set` statement.