# pipe delimited text file to csv file in vbscript

Tags: excel, text, vbscript, csv

I have a txt file with | delimited. i want to save that file in excel. Here's my code

```
' Define constants
Const xlDelimited = 1   
'The TSV file to be converted
strProdTextFile = "C:\Users\laxmi\Documents\Payroll\CompareFiles\SEACRDPRD01SVM_xLearnCom_10292018.txt"

'The Excel file to be created
strProdExcelFile = "C:\Users\laxmi\Documents\Payroll\CompareFiles\SEACRDPRD01SVM_xLearnCom_10292018.xls"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
objExcel.Visible = FALSE

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText(strProdTextFile,,,xlDelimited,,,,,,,True,"|")
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strProdExcelFile, 51

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
```

This is the error i am getting:

> Object required: 'objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText(...)'
>
> Line (14): "Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText(strProdTextFile,,,xlDelimited,,,,,,,True,"|")"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB Error "object required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266074/vb-error-object-required)

Answer (score 0):

[`Workbooks.OpenText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext) does not return a value, so your script is failing on

```
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText(...)
```

because `Set objWorkbook =` requires an object on the right hand side. Since your next line is using the `ActiveWorkbook` you can simply remove the `Set objWorkbook =` from the beginning of the line.

Comment: If i remove Set objWorkbook i am getting this error :
The test run cannot continue due to a syntax error.

Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub

Line (13): "objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText(strProdTextFile,,,xlDelimited,,,,,,,True,"|")".

Comment: Remove the parentheses (`(` and `)`) or put `Call` at the start of the line https://stackoverflow.com/a/6520868/3898606